# AC starts cold, then becomes warm

Tags: ford, hvac, mustang

2006 Ford Mustang - Ok so I've replaced the compressor clutch and accumulator. Every time the ac starts to blow cold the cooling fans turn on at the radiator and I can hear a click and the cooling system  to ac turns off, starts to blow warm air. Almost everything is new and not sure what issue could be.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How did you ensure you have the proper amount of refrigerant in the system? Did you do the repair or did you have a shop do it for you? If you did it, did you draw a vacuum on the system prior to putting refrigerant back in?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description either you do not have enough refrigerant in your AC system, intermittent failing relay for your compressor or your AC pressure sensor is faulty.